# Can we extract contact out of a running journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

[image]The situation is I have a running Journey with 4 paths, the entry source is DE. All first 3 paths are completed and contact are exited, i want to re-schedule the 4th path early then the intial schedule. Can anyone please help me to explore option how it can be done? thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific in describing your scenario? You can't "re-schedule a path" in Journey Builder.

Comment: Instead of waiting for the schedule time, i want to send email tomorrow to the population waiting in the 4th Path. Can i pull this audience into a data extension using SQL?

Comment: I have also added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the contacts to proceed from the wait step prematurely. Your only option is to download the list of Contact Keys in your wait step, by going into History, and filter on the journey in question, and on everyone who is currently in the wait step. You will be able to download these details as a CSV file:

[image]

This list can then be used to build a segment in a new custom data extension, to which you will be able to send the email immediately. I can see you have some additional steps, e.g. a decision split. You could consider building a journey which replicates your 4th path from the email activity and onwards, and use this data extension as your entry source.

Once you have exported the Contact Keys as per above, you should stop the journey and kick all the contacts out, as otherwise they will receive two emails: one from the existing and one from the new journey.